# SGMII without phy - external loopback on Xlinix Zynq UltraScale+ RFSoC board

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, ping, xilinx, raw-ethernet

I have a costume board with Xilinx Zynq UltraScale+ RFSoC.
I'm using 3 PS_GTR transceivers as sgmii.
2 of them are connected to external Marvell phy and the third connects directly (fixed link - without phy).

In the manufacturing stage i would like to make sure that the direct sgmii interface is assembled correctly - so I made an external loopback between tx and rx sgmii signals.
Now, Is it possible to transmit something through this external loopback and compare with the received data?
Is it possible to ping with yourself? (simple ping command not working: "ping -I eth2 ")

perhaps there is a 'patch' under the 'macb' kernel driver that someone can guide me through?

Thank you all,
Tzipi Kluska

Comment: I meant: 
"ping -I eth2 <eth2-ip-address>"

Comment: a phy will often have a prbs generator and checker that you can use.  Some may also have scope like tools to view the eye or to view numbers that represent the eye, etc.

Comment: worst case yes you can just use network traffic (this is network yes).  you have to trick the os into talking to itself (the machine talking to itself) through the loopback, which is doable.  Normally we do prbs first, use a high speed scope as well to see that signal, some scopes will do prbs decoding, then link up, understand some of these interfaces will have an idle pattern that has plenty of state changes so you can again look at the eye and quality of the signal.   Then go through a tuning phase with the loopback to adjust the transmitter and receiver

Comment: then work toward passing traffic.  ping floods and other things can be used there.  like iperf and netperf

Comment: if you have two ethernet devices on a system and you just try to ping the other address the ip stack in linux will bypass the hardware and talk to itself within the stack.  but it has been a while since I tried that.

Comment: your sgmii interface itself should have a phy on chip despite having another phy on the board.  look at what you are using for serdes on the edge of that sgmii and see what its features are.  If you are shorting the sgmii inside the fpga and not going off chip then you dont need to mess with this analog stuff, you may need to trick linux and then use ping and iperf and stuff.

Comment: okay serdes not necessrily phy...

Comment: When you do connect to the marvell phy they should also have prbs send and receive capabilities so you can again check and tune the link with that well before attempting to move packets.

Comment: also check in the fpga if the serdes has an internal loopback sometimes when it doesnt work it is not the analog side of it but software has not set up the interface right (also be aware that sometimes outer loopbacks (sometimes you have multiple layers in both directions) can have analog issues with something connected outside that is trying to train/talk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to ping yourself. Note that linux does or at least used to bypass the hardware when talking to itself and would do the loopback in the IP stack.  I recently saw someone within a terminal (window, command line) isolate one network interface, then another another network interface and then it was trivial to use stock tools like ping and iperf to test the link.

Before doing that though, the serdes on your part should have PRBS capabilities (for a reason), some may have internal scope like features that allow you to extract an eye or at least numbers that indicate the quality of the eye.  The marvell phy should also have this capability and you can both use a loopback to talk to yourself use various prbs lengths to check the quality of the link (less than one error in so many 10 to the 14th bits or whatever your desired quality is), and then when connected to the marvell repeat that.

Before doing all of this the software is often the hard part and you need to insure you have it working first, so you may wish to do loopbacks inside the fpga that do not have analog issues and get the software worked out, then in the serdes on the edge of the fpga they may have loopbacks in both directions, the marvell as well may have loopbacks in both directions so you can for example go direct fpga to marvell one is the tx and one the rx and vice versa, or you might enable a lan side shallow loopback on the marvell and talk to yourself.

Also depending on these speeds, hand made loopbacks might be noisy so sometimes a pcb based loopback (which also has to be designed) may wish to be deployed.

Can you ping yourself, absolutely.  You can use other low level network interfaces like sockets, to make raw packets and talk to yourself through these interfaces as well.  Ping, doing a ping flood, iperf, netperf, etc are all fine ways to exercise or get a warm fuzzy about the interface during both development and manufacture test.

Being an fpga you can of course have a test design that you load into the fpga that pushes the external interfaces and reports the bit error rate.